# How do I keep elements from moving when I scroll to the right?

Tags: html, css

So I made the header and footer on the right a fixed position. When I scroll up and down, it works perfectly fine, but when I scroll to the right, the elements move to the right as well, and that's something I don't want. I just want those elements to stay in a vertical position with the blue background behind it.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460602594182-8568137446ce?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% 5%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.profile-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 750px;
  top: 300px;
  border: 7px solid #A9A9A9;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.profile-image:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.name span {
  color: orange;
  position: relative;
}

.name {
  position: relative;
  left: 550px;
  top: 330px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lexend Zetta', sans-serif;
}

.header-background {
  background-color: #000033;
  height: 500rem;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 18rem;
}

hr {
  color: #3d3d5c;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 6rem;
  width: 17.9rem;
}

.header-links a {
  color: #cccfc2;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  left: 1rem;
  bottom: 4rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-links {
  position: fixed;
}

.header-links a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.footer-side-links a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}

.footer-side-links a:hover {
  color: orange
}

.footer-side-links {
  left: 3rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Zetta&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/82c7176f2a.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="profile">
    <img class="profile-image" src="https://gamerheadquarters.com/hub/avatar/fallout76tshirt.jpg" alt="profile picture">
    <figcaption class="name">JOHN <span>JOHNSON</span></figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="header-background">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <hr>
    <header>
      <nav class="header-links">
        <a href="#Home">Home</a>
        <a href="#About">About</a>
        <a href="#Projects">Projects</a>
        <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <footer>
      <nav class="footer-side-links">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/parham-javadi/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/papar24/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/pjfooeve09" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </nav>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood right. You must add position: fixed; in the .header-background class

```
.header-background {
    background-color: #000033;
    height: 500rem;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 18rem;
    position: fixed; /* <-------- */
}
```

Reply to comment to remove the horizontal scroller: Try to replace the classes: .profile .profile-image .name and .header-links with these below. I hope this works for you.

```
.profile {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 290px;
  margin-top: 250px;
}

.profile-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 7px solid #A9A9A9;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.name {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lexend Zetta', sans-serif;
}

.header-links {
  position: fixed;
  top: 300px;
}
```

Comment: That worked. How can I leave out the extra white spaces on the right? that way I don't have to scroll to the right

Comment: I made an addition to my post. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use parent div `position` as `fixed` instead of individual element
Disable horizontal scroll using `overflow-x:hidden`

```
.wrapper{
 height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
  width: 18rem; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
  position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111; /* Black */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 20px;
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460602594182-8568137446ce?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% 5%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.profile-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
 left: 40%;
  border: 7px solid #A9A9A9;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.profile-image:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.name span {
  color: orange;
  position: relative;
}

.name {
position: relative;
    left: 27%;
    top: 14px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Lexend Zetta', sans-serif;


}

.header-background {
  background-color: #000033;
  height: 500rem;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 18rem;
}

hr {
  color: #3d3d5c;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 6rem;
  width: 17.9rem;
}

.header-links a {
  color: #cccfc2;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  left: 1rem;
  bottom: 4rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-links { 
    width: 63%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.wrapper{
 height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
  width: 17%; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
  position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111; /* Black */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 20px;
  }

.header-links a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.footer-side-links a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}

.footer-side-links a:hover {
  color: orange
}

.footer-side-links {
width: 34%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
.container{
    width: 83%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-left: 282px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Zetta&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/82c7176f2a.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <header>
      <nav class="header-links">
        <a href="#Home">Home</a>
        <a href="#About">About</a>
        <a href="#Projects">Projects</a>
        <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <footer>
      <nav class="footer-side-links">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/parham-javadi/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/papar24/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/pjfooeve09" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </nav>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="profile">
      <img class="profile-image" src="https://gamerheadquarters.com/hub/avatar/fallout76tshirt.jpg" alt="profile picture">
      <figcaption class="name">JOHN <span>JOHNSON</span></figcaption>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</head>

</html>
```

[Screenshot](https://ibb.co/ypW4Yrb)

Comment: Is there anyway you could leave out the extra white spaces on the right? that way I don't have to scroll to the right

Comment: you means don't want horizontal scroll ?

Comment: Yes, only to scroll up and down (vertically)

Comment: there is lots wrong structured in html is it ok if clean it properly.

Comment: Of course, it allows me to better learn how to structure them

Comment: i have added code. you have to write media query to adapt responsiveness. its fixed for desktop and larger screen.